# How to get a checkbox to align with text from both sides

Tags: html, css

So I've just started to learn HTLM and CSS, so to learn I'm just going trough some easy to do examples. But I'm stuck on getting the checkbox to align with the texts I want to align it to.

[The example I'm following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEzBh.png)

And this is how mine looks at the moment:

[My copy of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dbBo.png)

As you can see it's not an exact copy of the example and I've tried for some hours now but can't figure it out.

This is my code:

```css
p {
  display: table-row;
}

label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="förnamn"> * Förnamn: </label>
  <input id="förnamn" type="text">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="efternamn"> * Efternamn: </label>
  <input id="efternamn" type="text">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="adress"> * Adress: </label>
  <input id="adress" type="text">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="e-post"> * E-post: </label>
  <input id="e-post" type="text">
</p>
<p>
  <label for="ålder">Ålder: </label>
  <select name="ålder" id="Ålder">
    <option value="över_18">Över 18</option>
    <option value="under_18">Under 18</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="meddelande">Meddelande: </label>
  <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" cols="18" rows="2"></textarea>
</p>

<p>
  <label for="välj">Välj låtar och media: </label>
</p>
<p class="checkbox">
  <label for="ringnes-ronny">Ringnes-Ronny</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen</label>
  <label>59 SEK</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox">Valhalla</label>
  <label for="39-sek">39 SEK</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen</label>
  <label for="49-sek">49 SEK</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox">Monster</label>
  <label for="59-sek">39 SEK</label>
</p>
```

I'm sorry if the code is sloppy, haven't figured out the whole structure yet but I hope its readable.
I've tried to change the display of the .checkbox but none of them does what I would want.
Tried the align and vertical-align but they don't move at all.

Comment: I think that you should use flexbox to do this. If you want to learn HTML & CSS this is your best option to position HTML elements (when you learn flexbox you can learn grid too). If you are interested: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: First tip for a stack overflow question. Remove what is irrelevant. All we're interested in is the check box section. Just show those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you had a pretty good start on it. I would put the items that I want to be beside each other into a flexbox, and I just moved the labels around so they would be where they are in the example that your following.

`display: flex` Is super powerful, I HIGHLY reccommend playing [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) to get a bit more comfortable with it in a fun and engaging way.

Another great tool that is used often to display thing how you want is `display: grid` and there is an online game for that one as well called [grid garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/).

```css
p {
    display: table-row;
}

label {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkbox {
    display:flex;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Lab1 </title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <label for="förnamn"> * Förnamn: </label>
        <input id="förnamn" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="efternamn"> * Efternamn: </label>
        <input id="efternamn" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="adress"> * Adress: </label>
        <input id="adress" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="e-post"> * E-post: </label>
        <input id="e-post" type="text">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="ålder">Ålder: </label>
        <select name="ålder" id="Ålder">
            <option value="över_18">Över 18</option>
            <option value="under_18">Under 18</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="meddelande">Meddelande: </label>
        <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" cols="18" rows="2"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="välj">Välj låtar och media: </label>
    </p>
    <p class="checkbox">
        <div class="flex">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen</label>
          <label >59 SEK</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Valhalla</label>
          <label for="39-sek">39 SEK</label>
        </div>
        
        <label for="ringnes-ronny">Ringnes-Ronny</label>
        
        <div class="flex">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen</label>
          <label for="49-sek">49 SEK</label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex">
          <label><input type="checkbox">Monster</label>
          <label for="59-sek">39 SEK</label>
        </div>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you add div and when would you use them? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: `<div>` is a tool that I use mainly for grouping things together. You can use as many `<div>`'s as you want with no repercussions. In this case I used them to apply the class `display: flex` to all the elements that are inside the individual `<div>`'s. The only time I wouldn't use a `<div>` would be if theres a more semantically accurate group tag to use, in this example you could have used `<div>`'s to hold your label and input fields (I probably would have done that) instead of using `<p>` tags. the `<p>` tag is mainly used for putting text characters inside, `<div>` is better for holding

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image supplied try the following. I've replaced `p` with a [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) as this is what a collection of check boxes is.

```css
.checkbox {
  /*Remove the border from the fieldset*/
  border: 0;
  /*Flex disply*/
  display:flex;  
  /*Start aligning to the left*/
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /*Vertical align center*/
  align-items: center;
}

.title {padding-right:1em;}
.boxContainer {
  /*Give the container some width*/
  min-width:40vw;
}

.checkbox label {
  /*Set labels to display be block elements*/
  display: block;
  /*Position relative so child elements are postions relative to this object*/
  position: relative;
  /*A little spacing*/
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  /*Give us some min width*/
  min-width:40vw;
}

.checkbox label input {
  /*A litle more spacing*/
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.checkbox .time {
  /*Set our time elements to be absolutely positioned*/
  position: absolute;
  /*THen move them to the right.*/
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="checkbox">
  <div class="title">Ringnes-Ronny</div>
  <div class="boxContainer">
    <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen<span class="time">59 SEK</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Valhalla<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Polisen<span class="time">49 SEK</span></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox">Monster<span class="time">39 SEK</span></label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: How would you make the <legend>Ringnes-Ronny</legend> be on the middle left of the checkboxes?

Comment: Legends are notoriously difficult to position. I've replaced it with a `div`

Answer (score 0):

maybe that...

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
}
#my-form > label {
  display     : block;
  width       : 24rem;
  min-height  : 2.5rem;
  font-size   : .9rem;
  line-height : 2rem;
  }
#my-form > label input[type=text],
#my-form > label select,
#my-form > label textarea  {
  font-size  : 1rem;
  float      : right;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  width      : 18rem;
 }
 #my-form > h3  {
  margin : 2.5rem 0 0 0;
  }
#my-form > fieldset  {
  display               : grid;
  grid-template-columns : 8rem 16rem;
  border                : none;
  margin                : 0;
  padding               : 0;
  font-size             : 1rem;
  }
#my-form > fieldset legend {
  transform: translateY(2rem);
  } 
#my-form > fieldset label {
  grid-column      : 2;
  } 
#my-form > fieldset label span {
  float  : right;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label> 
    * Förnamn:
    <input name="förnamn" type="text">
  </label>
  <label> 
    * Efternamn:
    <input name="efternamn" type="text"> 
  </label>
  <label> 
    * Adress: 
    <input name="adress" type="text">
  </label>
  <label> 
    * E-post:
    <input name="e-post" type="text"> 
  </label>
  <label>
    Ålder: 
    <select name="ålder">
      <option value="över_18">Över 18</option>
      <option value="under_18">Under 18</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    Meddelande: 
    <textarea name="meddelande" id="meddelande" rows="2"></textarea>
  </label>

  <h3> Välj låtar och media: </h3>
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>  Ringnes-Ronny </legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Polisen" value="59">
      Polisen
      <span>59 SEK</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Valhalla" value="39">
      Valhalla
      <span>39 SEK</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Polisen" value="49">
      Raggare pä stureplan
      <span>49 SEK</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Monster" value="39">
      Monster
      <span>39 SEK</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  
 </form>
```